# How to check customer login authentication in big commerce through PHP

Tags: bigcommerce

I have to check customer login authentication in our PHP application(by using bigcommerce api), how can i do so? I found api for customer details, forget password but not for customer login authentication from this url: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/customers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are attempting to validate a customers username and password using the API. If that is the case, this is not possible using any currently available API methods.

Answer (score 2):

Edited: Feb 2017 -- 1 year update

I would be cautious with that approach since you risk something in security by hosting unhashed password data.

send a `POST` to https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/[STORE_HASH]/v2/customers/[CUSTOMER_ID]/validate

containing JSON data with your password guess:

```
{
    "password": "abc123"
}
```

The response will be a boolean:

```
{
  "success": false
}
```

If the password was not valid, and:

```
{
  "success": true
}
```

If the password was correct.

Additional docs/postman collection: https://www.getpostman.com/collections/5b0aa777c99c96afc5e3

Answer (score 2):

From [Login to BigCommerce API through iOS Application as a customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369395/login-to-bigcommerce-api-through-ios-application-as-a-customer/36378723?noredirect=1#comment60450060_36378723) ...

You can validate a pair of credentials by sending a POST request to: 
`/remote.php?w=expressCheckoutLogin` | with`login_email` and `login_pass` as the POST body data.

Your response will be in JSON, and the status of the authentication attempt will be returned under the JSON property `status`, where 1 = successful login, and 0 = unsuccessful login.

*ScreenShot of cURL POST Request:*
[image]