# Login to BigCommerce API through iOS Application as a customer

Tags: ios, bigcommerce

I am developing an iOS application for a store on BigCommerce.com . I have successfully retrieved the products list from the BigCommerce API and I have also created a new user using the same.

Create User: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/customers#create-a-customer

Product List: 
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products

But i am unable to understand that how should i login into the BigCommerce Store as a customer to purchase products listed.

Please can anyone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can login by sending a POST to:

```
/remote.php?w=expressCheckoutLogin
```

Send fields 'login_email' and 'login_pass' in your POST's body.

Comment: Hey Donny, out of curiosity, how did you determine the functionality of remote.php? There is little docs online about it.. Did you just figure it out by analyzing template code, or do you have some sort of documentation on it?

Comment: I've never been able to find any official documentation on it.  When I need to reverse-engineer any functionality like this I've just done so by digging through the stock Bigcommerce theme JS, followed by a fair amount of trial and error.  The Postman extension for Chrome is super helpful in figuring out what params and headers are needed as well.

Comment: Yeah that has been my experience as well. I think BC is in the process of rewriting their codebase into Java, but either way, I'd love to collaborate with you on both our past BC R&D experiences. Will followup with you via your SO bio if you don't mind.

Comment: Absolutely, feel free...glad to swap notes and collaborate

Comment: We aren't in the process of rewriting our codebase in Java, for the purpose of clarity.

Comment: Hello Donny, i followed the steps you mentioned in your answer. Even after passing login_email and login_pass, i am getting the login page from website with empty text fields.

Comment: @AditBhargava, I've tested this and can confirm it works successfully. In fact, it should give you a JSON response, where status=1 means a successful login, and status=0 means unsuccessful. Take a peek here: `http://content.screencast.com/users/rmullins25/folders/Jing/media/43eaf7ff-6618-41a4-abc5-cf2125ac65bc/00000383.png`
A successful login is going to return a ton of other data, so I recommend just parsing the JSON and grabbing the `status` property.

Comment: @Empathy Thank you for you help. I have received the JSON response.

Comment: @DonnyWest Thank you for you help. I have received the JSON response.

Comment: @DonnyWest I know, Its being too long you worked on this. Just a quick Question, Will it give any Customer ID or Token ? Because, I am just getting status 1 with my email ID. No details regarding the store, access-rights, token or anything !!

Answer (score 1):

Its very hard to finding login api in bigCommerce. this solution is 100% working and tested.

Keep Enjoy

APi URL : https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/[STORE_HASH]/v2/customers/[CUSTOMER_ID]/validate

Method : POST

**Header** 
X-Auth-Client : Client_id
X-Auth-Token : Access Token
Accept :  application/json
Content-Type : application/json

**Body** 
{
   "password": "123456"
}

**Response** 
{
 "success": true
}

Comment: Hey @Ajay Hada,
Thanks for your answer. It is such a relief to see someone has the answer for this. I was trying to use this answer. Can I know from where shall I get "Customer ID" for hitting API ? I need to implement this in iOS App.