# Issue in OAuth Authentication for Bigcommerce

Tags: ios, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, bigcommerce

I am trying to get authentication done via OAuth for Bigcommerce. It looks easy but not happening at my end.

I got postman Bigcommerce APIs in collection. But there is no API for Customer Login API and when, I am trying to do it via OAUth it is not happening though it works fine with Basic Authentication.

1. I have created my draft App and successfully installed on Bigcommerce Store.
2. Created API Account > Client ID, Client Secret & Access token received.

**My Concerns**

1. How OAuth can be done for Bigcommerce ?

   [Please have a look to the settings for OAuth API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiQ10.png)

   Desired result :

   [Customer Login API with Basic Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UqAv.png)

This will help in logging in Customer Login

I tried Logging In: [Login to BigCommerce API through iOS Application as a customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369395/login-to-bigcommerce-api-through-ios-application-as-a-customer)

If anyone can provide some insight, I would appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to the documentation on the BigCommerce Oauth Customer Login API: 
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/storefront.html#customer_login_api

Your app would need to generate a [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/) using a payload containing the following claims:

```
{ 
"iss": "your Oauth Client ID", 
"iat": time token was generated (Unix), 
"jti": "This is a completely unique string, ideally a UUID", 
"operation": "customer_login", 
"store_hash": "abc123", 
"customer_id": 12345, 
"redirect_to": "/account.php", 
"request_ip": "111.222.333.444" 
}
```

The JWT is signed with your BigCommerce Oauth Client Secret.

Then, you would append the JWT to this login entry point URL to log the customer into their account:

https://storedomain.com/login/token/{JWT}

Comment: Hi @Karen Thanks for the reply. I had gone through this. I am going to try this. Just a quick question, Is there any way to authenticate the customer with username and password ?

Comment: Hi @Ruhii, With Oauth, using the Customer Login API is the only way to securely log into a customer account from your app. It isn't possible to authenticate the customer with their username and password. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: ok. So, I have tried creating payload using https://jwt.io/ so to use it on postman first. and used the token as you said but it is giving me "Invalid login. Please attempt to log in again."

Comment: @Ruhii Tokens expire within about 30 seconds, so the request to the access URL needs to be made pretty much right after the token is generated. You'll also want to make sure the timestamp is accurate--if it's a time in the future, or more than 30 seconds old, then the request will fail.

Comment: Ok. It was really useful input. I tried it again. Now, it is giving me 200 OK response but I am unable to get any response regarding login.

Comment: Have you tried making the request in the browser instead of Postman? You should be automatically logged in to the store when you hit the URL. Just be sure that the token you are using hasn't been accessed with a GET request before (each token is good for one request).

Comment: Can you please consider this query as well.. Appreciate your response.
https://forum.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D51B00004G5241SAB/how-can-i-make-payment-while-checkout-for-mobile-application-using-api-or-weblink

Comment: What to do after the url is generated?